# Find property by US State County

Tags: api

What is the best way to bring in US County information by state from any of the mapbox API's?  We're working on US residential property website and the data providers don't have county in the API's.

It doesn't look like mapbox has this in its core API either so I'm thinking we need to cross reference somehow. Or, I've just missed this in the structure somewhere and need help finding it.

Please advise.

gr8rck

Comment: `best way` has a different meaning to different people ... what is your definition of it?

Comment: A way that works would be just fine.  This is a react application if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's not mapbox, but here's an API with county information that may help.  There's an endpoint by state that seems like it might give you what you need.

https://rapidapi.com/aptitudeapps/api/us-counties/